# Show BottomPlayerView above TabView in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, tabbar

I'm learning swiftUI and I want to make a music app.

I created a view which going to be above the tabView, but I want it to be shown only if user start playing a music.

My App, I use ZStack for bottomPlayer, and I share the bottomPlayer variable through .environmentObject(bottomPlayer) so the child views can use it:

```
class BottomPlayer: ObservableObject {
    var show: Bool = false
}

@main
struct MyCurrentApp: App {
    var bottomPlayer: BottomPlayer = BottomPlayer()
    var audioPlayer = AudioPlayer()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .center, vertical: .bottom)) {
                TabBar()
                if bottomPlayer.show {
                    BottomPlayerView()
                        .offset(y: -40)
                }
            }
            .environmentObject(bottomPlayer)
        }
    }
}
```

The BottomPlayerView (above the TabView)

```
struct BottomPlayerView: View {
        var body: some View {
            HStack {
                Image("cover")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Artist")
                        .foregroundColor(.orange)
                    Text("Song title")
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                }
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    print("button")
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "play")
                }
                .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 60)
            .background(Color.white)
            .onTapGesture {
                print("ontap")
            }
        }
    }
```

My TabView:

```
struct TabBar: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            AudiosTabBarView()
            VideosTabBarView()
            SearchTabBarView()
        }
    }
}
```

And In my SongsView, I use the EnvironmentObject to switch on the bottomPlayerView

```
struct SongsView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var bottomPlayer: BottomPlayer

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button {
                    bottomPlayer.show = true
                } label: {
                    Text("Show Player")
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .navigationBarTitle("Audios")
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the bottomPlayer.show is actually set to true, but doesn't appear ...
Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your BottomPlayer add the @Published attribute before the show boolean.
This creates a publisher of this type.
[apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/published)

Comment: Also instantiate the BottomPlayer with @StateObject attribute

Comment: Amazing! It works! Thank you!
What's the difference between @State and @StateObject?

Comment: \@State should be used with simple struct types such as String, Int, and arrays.  – \@StateObject and \@ObservedObject is for ObservableObjects